How can I measure the size of a webpage in different devices?
I'm new with html and css, I'm wondering how can I measure the dimension of a webpage by pixels, is there any specific way like special code or app that I can use?
I tried searching but I somehow can't understand how it works.

If you're talking about finding out the width of someone else's website, you can use the developer console (right-click and press inspect in a browser.)
If you're talking about the width of your own website that you are coding, you can use viewport units. Viewport units are the size of your browser screen. In CSS 100vw will give you the width of the viewport in pixels, and 100vh will give you the height of the viewport in pixels.
For example, you could do something like the following:
HTML:
<div class="fullscreen">test</div>

CSS:
.fullscreen {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
}

This would give you a div that is as wide as the screen and as tall as it. You could use this for example to create a webpage where each section of your page scrolling vertically perfectly is the height of the screen.
Similarly width: 50vw would give you half of the viewport width, height: 25vh would give you a quarter of the viewport height. You could even do something silly like width: 100vh which would make the width of the element the same as the height of the viewport.
It's also important to note that these units are tied to the size of the viewport, not the size of the parent they may be inside. So if you have a div that is only 300px wide and 200px tall, and you put an object that is 100vw inside, it will overflow the container (assuming that the width of your viewport isn't smaller than 300px.) If you need something to fill a parent element, you can use percentages instead (for example width: 100% will fill the width of the parent element.)
You can read more about it in this article by CSS Tricks: Fun With Viewport Units

You're very welcome! If you feel like I answered your question, I would appreciate it if you would mark my answer as correct (the big checkmark near the answer), so that others with the same question can find this solution.
